# SSSD Kerberos AD Centos troubleshooting

Tags: active-directory, centos6, sssd

I followed the Configuration 3 from the RedHat AD integration (https://access.redhat.com/sites/default/files/attachments/rhel-ad-integration-deployment-guidelines-v1.5.pdf); but I am stuck.

I am on Centos 6.8.

I have a working AD connection:

```
 service sssd stop
 rm -r /var/lib/sss/db/*
 rm -r /var/lib/sss/mc/*
 service sssd start
 getent passwd robau@MYNETWORK.LOCAL
```

This returns a sensible line:

```
 robau:*:102201201:102200513:Rob Audenaerde:/:
```

However, when I try to connect over SSH, I can't login. I enabled SSSD debugging on all components level 5 in the `sssd.conf`.

The error I see (in `var/log/sssd/krb5_child.log`) is:

```
(Fri Jun 17 17:23:18 2016) [[sssd[krb5_child[3561]]]] [validate_tgt] (0x0020): TGT failed verification using key for [host/server-new.mynetwork.nl@MYNETWORK.LOCAL].
(Fri Jun 17 17:23:18 2016) [[sssd[krb5_child[3561]]]] [get_and_save_tgt] (0x0020): 1240: [-1765328377][Server not found in Kerberos database]
(Fri Jun 17 17:23:18 2016) [[sssd[krb5_child[3561]]]] [map_krb5_error] (0x0020): 1301: [-1765328377][Server not found in Kerberos database]
(Fri Jun 17 17:23:18 2016) [[sssd[krb5_child[3561]]]] [k5c_send_data] (0x0200): Received error code 1432158209
```

The server is in the DNS, I can find it using `nslookup`

```
   nslookup server-new.mynetwork.nl

   Server:  192.168.110.56
   Address: 192.168.110.56#53

   Name:    server-new.mynetwork.nl
   Address: 192.168.210.94
```

And

```
kvno host/server-new.mynetwork.nl@MYNETWORK.LOCAL
kvno: Server not found in Kerberos database while getting credentials for host/server-new.mynetwork.nl@MYNETWORK.LOCAL
```

Any hints/tips for troubleshooting?

[EDIT]
I used `authconfig` to setup the necessary `pam` and `nss` stuff:

```
authconfig --enablesssdauth --enablesssd --enablemkhomedir --update
```

Output of `klist -kte`:

```
  25 06/20/16 10:56:24 host/server-new.mynetwork.nl@MYNETWORK.LOCAL (des-cbc-crc) 
  25 06/20/16 10:56:24 host/server-new.mynetwork.nl@MYNETWORK.LOCAL (des-cbc-md5) 
  25 06/20/16 10:56:24 host/server-new.mynetwork.nl@MYNETWORK.LOCAL (aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96) 
  25 06/20/16 10:56:24 host/server-new.mynetwork.nl@MYNETWORK.LOCAL (aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96) 
  25 06/20/16 10:56:24 host/server-new.mynetwork.nl@MYNETWORK.LOCAL (arcfour-hmac) 
  25 06/20/16 10:56:24 host/server-new@MYNETWORK.LOCAL (des-cbc-crc) 
  25 06/20/16 10:56:24 host/server-new@MYNETWORK.LOCAL (des-cbc-md5) 
  25 06/20/16 10:56:25 host/server-new@MYNETWORK.LOCAL (aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96) 
  25 06/20/16 10:56:25 host/server-new@MYNETWORK.LOCAL (aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96) 
  25 06/20/16 10:56:25 host/server-new@MYNETWORK.LOCAL (arcfour-hmac) 
  25 06/20/16 10:56:25 SERVER-NEW$@MYNETWORK.LOCAL (des-cbc-crc) 
  25 06/20/16 10:56:25 SERVER-NEW$@MYNETWORK.LOCAL (des-cbc-md5) 
  25 06/20/16 10:56:25 SERVER-NEW$@MYNETWORK.LOCAL (aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96) 
  25 06/20/16 10:56:25 SERVER-NEW$@MYNETWORK.LOCAL (aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96) 
  25 06/20/16 10:56:26 SERVER-NEW$@MYNETWORK.LOCAL (arcfour-hmac)
```

Output of `klist`

```
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_0
Default principal: SERVER-NEW$@MYNETWORK.LOCAL

Valid starting     Expires            Service principal
06/20/16 10:56:41  06/20/16 20:56:41  krbtgt/MYNETWORK.LOCAL@MYNETWORK.LOCAL
    renew until 06/27/16 10:56:41
06/20/16 11:36:07  06/20/16 20:56:41  ldap/my-ad.mynetwork.local@MYNETWORK.LOCAL
    renew until 06/27/16 10:56:41
```

[EDIT 2]

If I add `krb5_validate` at the end of the `sssd.conf` section [domain/mynetwork.local] then I am able to login. However, I also set-up another server that did not need this step, so I'm reluctant to leave it like this.

[EDIT 3]
During the `net ads join -k` I get an error/warning:

```
DNS Update for failed: ERROR_DNS_GSS_ERROR 
DNS update failed!
```

[EDIT 4]
I see the output of `net ads info` is not using the main Domain controller I specified in my config files (and is 2003R2 and not 2008R2). Is there a way to 'force' the `net ads join -k` to use a specific domain controller?

Comment: Did you run a `kinit` yet?
Can you also post output of `klist -te` and `klist -kte`.

The server needs a local Kerberos ticket cache to be able to do password authentication.

And is your pam configuration correct, I assume yes but you didn't mention it.

Comment: Yes. I did a `kinit admin`, `net join ads -k` and `kinit -k SERVER-NEW$`

Comment: What is the name of the computer account in AD? AD tends to use the hostname (not fqdn) in lowercase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try installing and running `msktutil` (it is available through EPEL).

To install:

```
yum -y --enablerepo=epel install msktutil
```

To run it:

```
msktutil --auto-update --server my-ad --verbose
```

And run a kinit after that:

```
kinit -k server-new$
```

Also, You should cron these two jobs to run every 6 hours or so. That way your tickets do not expire.

Answer to EDIT4: you should be able to specify a server with `net ads join -k -S`, but by default it will search your DNS for SRV records. Which is fine. Unless you don't want that.
If you want a specific site to use different DC's than another, look at Active Directory Sites & Services.

Comment: Thank you @aairey; do you think the problem is that my tickets expire? I would think they should at least stay valid for 10h (the TGT if I am correct). I ran into the problem directly after setting-up sssd, kerberos etc.

Comment: No. But the kerberos server cannot find the name that your client is sending. `msktutil` takes care of this for you and creates principals that AD likes.

Comment: Ah I see. Am I correct to assume the `net join ads -k` did not create proper tickets?  (see also edit 4)

Comment: It uses principals based on MIT Kerberos. As always, Microsoft needs to be "special" and has developed it's own, slightly deferring, standards. (updated answer on edit4)

Comment: Btw, it's much easier in CentOS 7 with `realmd` :) and on CentOS 5 ... good luck you're on your own there :D

Answer (score 3):

This is usually caused by canonicalization. Try adding:

```
rdns=false
```

to krb5.conf and also

```
SASL_NOCANON true
```

to ldap.conf

(both are already the default in RHEL-7).

Comment: The first setting did not change the behaviour.

Comment: `rdns=false` took care of it for me. The client I was trying to join had a hostname (from DHCP) that wasn't in the AD domain.